# Создание колонки в SQL формат Date + сортировка

Tags: sql, mysqli

Как я могу создать таблицу с колонкой в формате Date dd/mm/yyyy и сортировать ее потом с ORDER BY?

Comment: *"Как я могу создать таблицу с колонкой в формате Date"* -- очень просто. Нужно создать колонку с типом `DATE`. Подробности - [в документации](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html).

Comment: Проблема что там формат yyyy/mm/dd а мне надо dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: вас не должно волновать как именно хранится дата внутри БД. Сортировка будет работать в любом случае, а выводить значения вы можете в любом формате, как захотите. Попробуйте всё-таки почитать документацию (и лучше это делать до того, как задавать подобные вопросы...)

Comment: Но проблема когда я делаю сортировку через ORDER BY я не получаю нужный результат, а именно, например, у меня есть дата 15/3/2016 и 15/2/2016, я хочу видеть дату 15/2/2016 первой, а я вижу 15/3/2016

Comment: То есть совет почитать документацию вы принципиально игнорируете....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет никакой необходимости вмешиваться в способы хранить дату в БД. База сама разберётся как ей удобней это делать. А если речь идёт о  представлении даты на пользовательской стороне, на то есть [функции работы с датами](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Пример:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS datetest;
CREATE TABLE datetest ( td DATE );
INSERT INTO datetest (td) VALUES 
  (STR_TO_DATE('15/3/2016','%d/%c/%Y')), 
  (STR_TO_DATE('15/2/2016','%d/%c/%Y'));
```

Выборка раз:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(td, '%d/%c/%Y') FROM datetest ORDER BY td;
```

Результат:

```
15/2/2016
15/3/2016
```

Выборка два:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(td, '%d/%c/%Y') FROM datetest ORDER BY td DESC;
```

Результат:

```
15/3/2016
15/2/2016
```

Comment: Спасибо........